# C program not evaluating conditional properly

Tags: c

I have a program , that should reset a certain valriable , if the n + 1th value in a given array is nonexistant i.e. NULL , even if the value is null - which is being verified through a print statement , the program does not consistently behave like this.

The value that is equal to null is **next** , whish is also equal to
(*globalnodeSet[Z1]).memPool[((*globalnodeSet[Z1]).pc) + 1][0])

```
int startFunction(void* execState)
{
    while(1)
    {
        int *x = (int*)execState;
        if (*x == 1 )
        {
           for(;;)
           {
            // 1 second time gap between cycles
            Sleep(200);
            
            //program counter increments and so does the  active node
            Z1 ++; (*globalnodeSet[Z1]).pc++;(*globalnodeSet[Z1]).acc++;
            
            
            //logic loop

            printf("\nrunning - CCX:%u PC: %u\n",Z1 ,(*globalnodeSet[Z1]).pc);
            printf("the next instruction in memory is : %s\n",(*globalnodeSet[Z1]).memPool[((*globalnodeSet[Z1]).pc) + 1][0]);
            //if last core is reached
            if (Z1 == 11)
            {
                int counter = 0;
                for(counter = 0; counter <= 11; counter++)
                {
                    //reset loop and increment all program counters
                    //checks if next instruction exists at all
                    char *next = (*globalnodeSet[counter]).memPool[((*globalnodeSet[counter]).pc) + 1][0];
            
                    if(next == NULL)
                    {
                        //if no next instruction exists - set the program counter to -1 so that the first , 0th instruction will be executed on the next cycle.
                        (*globalnodeSet[counter]).pc = -1;
                    } else printf("not null\n");               
                }
                //loop counter is reset
                Z1 = - 1;
            } 

            //if the end of a node's instruction is reached , either pc = 11 or no next instruction exists
            if((*globalnodeSet[Z1]).pc == 11 || (*globalnodeSet[Z1]).memPool[((*globalnodeSet[Z1]).pc) + 1][0] == NULL)
            {
                //reset the program counter
                (*globalnodeSet[Z1]).pc = -1;
            }            
            //if stop button is pressed
            if (*x == 0) return 0;
            //we are using pointers so sim values are still retained upon function exit
           }           
        } 
    }
}
```

the output for this section of the program is as follows:

```
running - CCX:0 PC: 0
the next instruction in memory is : (null)

running - CCX:1 PC: 0
the next instruction in memory is : (null)

running - CCX:2 PC: 0
the next instruction in memory is : (null)

running - CCX:3 PC: 0
the next instruction in memory is : (null)

running - CCX:4 PC: 0
the next instruction in memory is : (null)

running - CCX:5 PC: 0
the next instruction in memory is : (null)

running - CCX:6 PC: 0
the next instruction in memory is : (null)

running - CCX:7 PC: 0
the next instruction in memory is : (null)

running - CCX:8 PC: 0
the next instruction in memory is : (null)

running - CCX:9 PC: 0
the next instruction in memory is : (null)

running - CCX:10 PC: 0
the next instruction in memory is : (null)

running - CCX:11 PC: 0
the next instruction in memory is : (null)
not null
not null
not null
not null
not null
not null
not null
not null
not null
not null
not null
```

It can be seen in the output that - it is infact equal to NULL
however the program doens't consistently behave as such , instead printing "not null" in the second print statement, instead of NULL , as it does in the first.

Comment: Instead of writing `(*ptr).field`, use `ptr->field`.  Don't fight the language.  Your code would be far more readable, and hence less likely to contain errors, if you used standard syntax.

Comment: you use many global object and we do not know what they are. How can we tell what is wrong?

Comment: The two printfs are completely unrelated. The first printf uses Z1 as the index, and is  called for all values of Z1. The second printf only runs when Z1 is 11, and uses `counter` as the index. Meanwhile, the chunk of code at the end of the `while` loop is setting all of the `pc` to -1.

Comment: When debugging with printf, you should always have a printf in every branch. In other words, code like `if (...) { dosomething(); } else { printf("B\n"); }` should be `if (...) { printf("A\n"); dosomething(); } else { printf("B\n"); }` And, the printf should have all of the relevant information, e.g. `printf("Z1=%u counter=%d: not null\n", Z1, counter);`

Comment: Please edit question so it's a [mre].

Comment: If `*x != 1` this is infinite loop, right?

Comment: The common idiom in C is `counter = 0; counter < 12` not `<= 11`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There are 12 nodes, node0 to node11.
- When the last node is reached the current node is reset to -1 – so the current node is the 0th (first) at the start of the next cycle.
- The program checks if the current node’s program counter needs to be reset.
- No such -1th node exists.

Hence the program crashes.